# Visio VBA - Adding Shape Data Properties

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio, shapesheet

i'm creating and testing a UserForm where user can add the shapes and add the predefined Shape Data Value to the Shape Data. The Shape Data name is "Element" as you can see the image below.

[image]

```
Dim vsoRound As Visio.Shape
Dim cell As Visio.cell

If (CheckBox1.Value) Then

Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop Application.Documents.Item("MS Icons.VSSX").Masters.ItemU("Round"), 5, 5

Set vsoRound = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemU("Round")

vsoRound.CellsU("ELement").FormulaU = """Fan"""
```

The value for this Shape Data is Fan. However it break at the last line of the code.

**Update:
I added the error message.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Document stencil window]

As workaround you can delete unused master *Square* in **Visio Shape Test.vssm** before drop master with same name from stencil **MS Icons.vssx** via your code!

Answer (score 0):

Try add prefix.

> vsoRound.CellsU("Prop.ELement").FormulaU = """Fan"""

Comment: Shape Data used to be called Custom Properties and so the "Prop." reference remains.  See this link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/shape-data-row-shape-data-section

Comment: Still same, i still get the error message and break.
On the same note. should i define the shape as Visio.Shape or Visio.Master?

Comment: Is property *Prop.Element* exist for master before drop?

Comment: No, as you can see the image above, i define vsoShape as Visio.Shape then drop the shape.

**Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop Application.Documents.Item("MS Icons.VSSX").Masters.ItemU("Round"), 5, 5**

Do i need to define the property before drop?

Comment: I mean: this property exist for main shape shape is master-shape into stencil **MS Icons.vssx**

Comment: Yes, the property is already exist in the Shape. I created the shape and added the "Element" property manually and added to the MS Icons.vssx stencil

Comment: Can you share your simple document with single dropped shape at GoogleDrive or other cloud share?

Comment: Just checked your document **Visio Shape Test.vssm**, and find in build-in Document stencil master named *Square*! This master shape have not fill color and this priperty!!! When you drop new shape from stencil **MS Icons.vssx**, new master in Document stencil will have name like *Square.740*. This is reason of this error!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240914/discussion-between-surrogate-and-mg78).